# How to make a circle semi-transparent in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm somewhat new to `pygame` and trying to figure out how to make a circle semi-transparent. The trick however is that the background for the circle also has to be transparent. Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
size = 10
surface = pygame.Surface(size, size), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
pygame.draw.circle(
    surface, 
    pygame.Color("black"),
    (int(size/2), int(size/2)),
    int(size/2), 2)
```

I tried using `surface.set_alpha(127)` but that didn't work. I'm assuming because the `surface` is already transparent.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using convert_alpha() on the surface

Comment: @gkusner That didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things. First, your surface definition should crash, as it missing a parenthesis. It should be:

```
surface = pygame.Surface((size, size), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
```

I assume that somewhere later in your code, you have something to the effect of:

```
mainWindow.blit(surface, (x, y))
pygame.display.update() #or flip
```

Here is your real problem:

```
>>> import pygame
>>> print pygame.Color("black")
(0, 0, 0, 255)
```

Notice that 255 at the end. That means that pygame.Color("black") returns a fully opaque color. Whereas `(0, 0, 0, 0)` would be fully transparent. If you want to set the transparency, define the color directly. That would make your draw function look like:

```
pygame.draw.circle(
    surface, 
    (0, 0, 0, transparency), 
    (int(size/2), int(size/2)),
    int(size/2), 2)
```