# How to draw a semi-transparent circle in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to draw a semi-transparent circle in Pygame. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

while True:
    msElapsed = clock.tick(100)
    screen.fill((0,0,0,255))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(30,224,33,100),(250,100),10)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

I want to use RGBA as circle color. But the circle is fully colored.
What's the problem with my code?

Comment: According to [the docs for `pygame.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html): "These can also accept an RGBA quadruplet. The alpha value will be written directly into the Surface if it contains pixel alphas, but the draw function will not draw transparently."

Comment: Do you mean that there is no way to draw a transparent shape? @abarnert

Comment: Apparently not with `pygame.draw`.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350227/8881141

Comment: How about refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989468/how-to-make-a-circle-semi-transparent-in-pygame)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fix:**

First you need to create a surface which accepts transparency

```
surface = pygame.Surface((width,height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

Then from this line:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen,(30,224,33,100),(250,100),10)
```

*CHANGE `screen` TO `surface` SO IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE:*

```
pygame.draw.circle(surface,(30,224,33,100),(250,100),10)
```

and after that add:

```
screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
```

**Explanation:**

When you were drawing the circle onto the screen it ignored the transparency values as the pygame screen cannot accept them. What I have done is created a new layer/screen which can accept transparency (due to this argument `pygame.SRCALPHA`) and then pasted that layer/screen on top of the original screen.

Answer (score 0):

this one wokred for me

```
def draw_transparent_circle(win,x,y,radius,color,alpha_level):
    pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(win,x,y,radius,(color[0],color[1],color[2],alpha_level))
```