# How do I make a circle semi-transparent in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a partially transparent circle as an area of effect indicator, but I haven't found any way to do this in pygame.

I tried passing in an rgba 4-tuple as an argument (as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989468/how-to-make-a-circle-semi-transparent-in-pygame)), but it didn't change the transparency at all. On top of that, according to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339057/draw-a-transparent-rectangle-in-pygame), the method shouldn't work at all, since draw doesn't accept alpha values. That's conflicting information.

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0, 100), (x, y), r)
```

I've also tried creating a new surface, drawing the circle onto that surface, and then blitting the new surface onto my game screen (as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229740/how-to-draw-a-semi-transparent-circle-in-pygame)). It gives me a semi-transparent circle as requested, but since surfaces in pygame are rectangular, it also gives me a gray rectangle around the circle, which I don't want.

```
s = pygame.Surface((1000, 1000))
s.set_alpha(100)
pygame.draw.circle(s, (255, 0, 0), (x, y), r)
screen.blit(s, (0, 0))
```

Is there any way to make this circle semi-transparent without adding any other visible effects to my screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a runnable version of the answer to the last question you linked to titled [How to draw a semi-transparent circle in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229740/how-to-draw-a-semi-transparent-circle-in-pygame). It seems to do what you want, as far as I can tell.

```
import pygame

width, height = 640, 480

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height), pygame.SRCALPHA)

while True:
    msElapsed = clock.tick(100)
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.draw.circle(surface,(30,224,33,100),(250,100),10)
    screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was just missing the pygame.SRCALPHA flag on the new surface.